# Quickbooks Online API PHP SDK cannot update Bill with values returned from query

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

According to QBO docs, in order to update the contents of a bill you should

```
Use this operation to update any of the writable fields of an existing bill object. The request body must include all writable fields of the existing object as returned in a read response. Writable fields omitted from the request body are set to NULL. The ID of the object to update is specified in the request body.
```

We query a bill like so

```
SELECT * FROM Bill where DocNumber='150577' and VendorRef='156'
```

It returns the following:

```
   (
    [0] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPBill Object
        (
            [PayerRef] =>
            [SalesTermRef] =>
            [DueDate] => 2020-10-22
            [RemitToAddr] =>
            [ShipAddr] =>
            [Balance] => 89.59
            [HomeBalance] => 89.59
            [BillEx] =>
            [VendorRef] => 156
            [APAccountRef] => 46
            [TotalAmt] => 89.59
            [BillEmail] =>
            [ReplyEmail] =>
            [Memo] =>
            [GlobalTaxCalculation] => TaxExcluded
            [DocNumber] => 150577
            [TxnDate] => 2020-10-22
            [DepartmentRef] =>
            [CurrencyRef] => CAD
            [ExchangeRate] => 1
            [PrivateNote] =>
            [TxnStatus] =>
            [LinkedTxn] =>
            [Line] => Array
                (
                    [0] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPLine Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 1
                            [LineNum] => 1
                            [Description] =>
                            [Amount] => 54.02
                            [LinkedTxn] =>
                            [DetailType] => AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail
                            [PaymentLineDetail] =>
                            [DiscountLineDetail] =>
                            [TaxLineDetail] =>
                            [SalesItemLineDetail] =>
                            [DescriptionLineDetail] =>
                            [ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail] =>
                            [AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPAccountBasedExpenseLineDetail Object
                                (
                                    [CustomerRef] =>
                                    [ClassRef] =>
                                    [AccountRef] => 40
                                    [BillableStatus] => NotBillable
                                    [MarkupInfo] =>
                                    [TaxAmount] =>
                                    [TaxCodeRef] => 22
                                    [TaxInclusiveAmt] =>
                                    [ExpenseDetailLineDetailEx] =>
                                )

                            [DepositLineDetail] =>
                            [PurchaseOrderItemLineDetail] =>
                            [SalesOrderItemLineDetail] =>
                            [ItemReceiptLineDetail] =>
                            [JournalEntryLineDetail] =>
                            [GroupLineDetail] =>
                            [SubTotalLineDetail] =>
                            [TDSLineDetail] =>
                            [CustomField] =>
                            [LineEx] =>
                        )

                    [1] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPLine Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 2
                            [LineNum] => 2
                            [Description] =>
                            [Amount] => 23.88
                            [LinkedTxn] =>
                            [DetailType] => AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail
                            [PaymentLineDetail] =>
                            [DiscountLineDetail] =>
                            [TaxLineDetail] =>
                            [SalesItemLineDetail] =>
                            [DescriptionLineDetail] =>
                            [ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail] =>
                            [AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPAccountBasedExpenseLineDetail Object
                                (
                                    [CustomerRef] =>
                                    [ClassRef] =>
                                    [AccountRef] => 37
                                    [BillableStatus] => NotBillable
                                    [MarkupInfo] =>
                                    [TaxAmount] =>
                                    [TaxCodeRef] => 22
                                    [TaxInclusiveAmt] =>
                                    [ExpenseDetailLineDetailEx] =>
                                )

                            [DepositLineDetail] =>
                            [PurchaseOrderItemLineDetail] =>
                            [SalesOrderItemLineDetail] =>
                            [ItemReceiptLineDetail] =>
                            [JournalEntryLineDetail] =>
                            [GroupLineDetail] =>
                            [SubTotalLineDetail] =>
                            [TDSLineDetail] =>
                            [CustomField] =>
                            [LineEx] =>
                        )

                    [2] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPLine Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 3
                            [LineNum] => 3
                            [Description] =>
                            [Amount] => 0
                            [LinkedTxn] =>
                            [DetailType] => AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail
                            [PaymentLineDetail] =>
                            [DiscountLineDetail] =>
                            [TaxLineDetail] =>
                            [SalesItemLineDetail] =>
                            [DescriptionLineDetail] =>
                            [ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail] =>
                            [AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPAccountBasedExpenseLineDetail Object
                                (
                                    [CustomerRef] =>
                                    [ClassRef] =>
                                    [AccountRef] => 94
                                    [BillableStatus] => NotBillable
                                    [MarkupInfo] =>
                                    [TaxAmount] =>
                                    [TaxCodeRef] => 22
                                    [TaxInclusiveAmt] =>
                                    [ExpenseDetailLineDetailEx] =>
                                )

                            [DepositLineDetail] =>
                            [PurchaseOrderItemLineDetail] =>
                            [SalesOrderItemLineDetail] =>
                            [ItemReceiptLineDetail] =>
                            [JournalEntryLineDetail] =>
                            [GroupLineDetail] =>
                            [SubTotalLineDetail] =>
                            [TDSLineDetail] =>
                            [CustomField] =>
                            [LineEx] =>
                        )

                )

            [TxnTaxDetail] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPTxnTaxDetail Object
                (
                    [DefaultTaxCodeRef] =>
                    [TxnTaxCodeRef] =>
                    [TotalTax] => 11.69
                    [TaxLine] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPLine Object
                        (
                            [Id] =>
                            [LineNum] =>
                            [Description] =>
                            [Amount] => 11.69
                            [LinkedTxn] =>
                            [DetailType] => TaxLineDetail
                            [PaymentLineDetail] =>
                            [DiscountLineDetail] =>
                            [TaxLineDetail] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPTaxLineDetail Object
                                (
                                    [TaxRateRef] => 37
                                    [PercentBased] => true
                                    [TaxPercent] => 15
                                    [NetAmountTaxable] => 77.90
                                    [TaxInclusiveAmount] =>
                                    [OverrideDeltaAmount] =>
                                    [ServiceDate] =>
                                    [TaxLineDetailEx] =>
                                )

                            [SalesItemLineDetail] =>
                            [DescriptionLineDetail] =>
                            [ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail] =>
                            [AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail] =>
                            [DepositLineDetail] =>
                            [PurchaseOrderItemLineDetail] =>
                            [SalesOrderItemLineDetail] =>
                            [ItemReceiptLineDetail] =>
                            [JournalEntryLineDetail] =>
                            [GroupLineDetail] =>
                            [SubTotalLineDetail] =>
                            [TDSLineDetail] =>
                            [CustomField] =>
                            [LineEx] =>
                        )

                )

            [TxnSource] =>
            [TaxFormType] =>
            [TaxFormNum] =>
            [TransactionLocationType] =>
            [Id] => 282835
            [SyncToken] => 0
            [MetaData] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPModificationMetaData Object
                (
                    [CreatedByRef] =>
                    [CreateTime] => 2020-10-22T14:40:58-07:00
                    [LastModifiedByRef] =>
                    [LastUpdatedTime] => 2020-10-22T14:40:58-07:00
                    [LastChangedInQB] =>
                    [Synchronized] =>
                )

            [CustomField] =>
            [AttachableRef] =>
            [domain] =>
            [status] =>
            [sparse] =>
        )

)
```

We then make some modifications and attempt to repost the updated data using

```
            $out = Bill::update($qb_data_original, $qb_data_updated);
            $config = $oAuthKeys->getAsArray();
            $resultingBillObj = $dataService->Update($out);
            print_r($resultingBillObj);
```

But the error we get says

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Can't convert Passed Parameter to IPPReferenceType. in /var/www/html/vendor/quickbooks/v3-php-sdk/src/Facades/FacadeHelper.php:293
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\FacadeHelper::getIPPReferenceTypeBasedOnArray(NULL, 'PayerRef')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/quickbooks/v3-php-sdk/src/Facades/FacadeHelper.php(195): ReflectionMethod->invoke(NULL, NULL, 'PayerRef')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/quickbooks/v3-php-sdk/src/Facades/FacadeHelper.php(117): QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\FacadeHelper::getComplexListObject('getIPPReference...', 'PayerRef', NULL)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/quickbooks/v3-php-sdk/src/Facades/Bill.php(8): QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\FacadeHelper::reflectArrayToObject('Bill', Array, true)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/quickbooks/v3-php-sdk/src/Facades/Bill.php(17): QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\Bill::create(Array)
#5 /var/www/html/qb_match.php(214): QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\Bill::update(Object(QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPBill), Array)
#6 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/quickbooks/v3-php-sdk/src/Facades/FacadeHelper.php on line 293
```

It seems its getting stuck on `PayerRef` which is the fist value in the result.

What is really odd, is that on the API Explorer when we run the same query it returns a much smaller set of data (itdoes not include the 'PayerRef' value) and if we then post ***that*** data back in the API explorer (in the update section) it works fine. This is the results from API explorer

```
{
 "QueryResponse": {
  "Bill": [
   {
    "DueDate": "2020-10-22",
    "Balance": 89.59,
    "HomeBalance": 89.59,
    "domain": "QBO",
    "sparse": false,
    "Id": "282835",
    "SyncToken": "0",
    "MetaData": {
     "CreateTime": "2020-10-22T14:40:58-07:00",
     "LastUpdatedTime": "2020-10-22T14:40:58-07:00"
    },
    "DocNumber": "150577",
    "TxnDate": "2020-10-22",
    "CurrencyRef": {
     "value": "CAD",
     "name": "Canadian Dollar"
    },
    "ExchangeRate": 1,
    "Line": [
     {
      "Id": "1",
      "LineNum": 1,
      "Amount": 54.02,
      "LinkedTxn": [],
      "DetailType": "AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail",
      "AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail": {
       "AccountRef": {
        "value": "40",
        "name": "Purchases"
       },
       "BillableStatus": "NotBillable",
       "TaxCodeRef": {
        "value": "22"
       }
      }
     },
     {
      "Id": "2",
      "LineNum": 2,
      "Amount": 23.88,
      "LinkedTxn": [],
      "DetailType": "AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail",
      "AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail": {
       "AccountRef": {
        "value": "37",
        "name": "Shipping"
       },
       "BillableStatus": "NotBillable",
       "TaxCodeRef": {
        "value": "22"
       }
      }
     },
     {
      "Id": "3",
      "LineNum": 3,
      "Amount": 0,
      "LinkedTxn": [],
      "DetailType": "AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail",
      "AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail": {
       "AccountRef": {
        "value": "94",
        "name": "otherFees"
       },
       "BillableStatus": "NotBillable",
       "TaxCodeRef": {
        "value": "22"
       }
      }
     }
    ],
    "TxnTaxDetail": {
     "TotalTax": 11.69,
     "TaxLine": [
      {
       "Amount": 11.69,
       "DetailType": "TaxLineDetail",
       "TaxLineDetail": {
        "TaxRateRef": {
         "value": "37"
        },
        "PercentBased": true,
        "TaxPercent": 15,
        "NetAmountTaxable": 77.9
       }
      }
     ]
    },
    "VendorRef": {
     "value": "156",
     "name": "vendora"
    },
    "APAccountRef": {
     "value": "46",
     "name": "Accounts Payable (A/P)"
    },
    "TotalAmt": 89.59,
    "GlobalTaxCalculation": "TaxExcluded"
   }
  ],
  "startPosition": 1,
  "maxResults": 1,
  "totalCount": 1
 },
 "time": "2020-11-22T10:01:06.526-08:00"
}
```

So, what is the reason for this error? Is it because the data set is unexpected and if so how do we return the same data set that appears in the API Explorer?

Thank you